# 16 divs arranging columns and rows with size dynamically by keeping its aspect ratio intact

Tags: css, flexbox, css-grid

I want to create 16 divs that arranging columns and rows with size dynamically by keeping its aspect ratio intact.

like First being 2x big as rest and all others stays with the same.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ri1X2.jpg)
With all of same size, [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O5y9M.png)

This is the code

.video-container {position: relative; overflow: hidden; width: 100%;  height: 100%;}
video { width: 100%; height: 100%; object-fit: cover;}

I tried to do but couldnt get anything

Comment: A tiny snippet of CSS on its own, tells us very little. Please present a proper [mre] of your issue, when asking this kind of question.

Answer (score 1):

Use CSS grid for that:

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4,auto);
}

.container > * {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

</div>
```

Comment: Now with this solution all container elements are taking large size on the video

Comment: I solved it using react-grid-layout, as i was building this feature in react.